# How Do Low Kinetic Energy and High Kinetic Energy Atoms Attraction differ?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, energy, kinematics, subatomic

Will atoms of 2 difrent energy levels electron and/or Kinetic attract more than 2 Atoms at he same energy level? Do 2 high energy level atoms attract more than 2 low energy atoms?

Comment: Why do you think they will attract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kinetic energy of an atom is not a uniquely defined quantity because it depends on the inertial frame. In the rest frame of the atom the kinetic energy is zero. However if by *energy of the atom* you mean the energy associated with its electron configuration then yes this can have an effect of the interaction between atoms.

For example the ground state of the helium atom has spin zero, and the interaction between ground state helium atoms is through a [London dispersion force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_dispersion_force), which is fairly weak. However the first excited state of helium, $1s^12s^1$, is a triplet state with spin 1. Two helium atoms in this state will interact far more strongly due to their non-zero spin.

Exactly how excited states of atoms will interact is complicated with few general rules, so it needs to be studied on case by case basis. However the general principle is that excited states of atoms will generally interact with each other differently to the ground states.